# Why do I need for a c program exactly four steps

Tags: c, compilation, linker

Why do I need for a c program exactly four steps if I want to create an executable file? Precompiler, compiler, assembler and linking. I didn't get the point why do I need the compiler step if it's only create symbolic machine code. If you use in gcc the command gcc -c it makes compilation and assembling in one step (and generates *.o-files).

Comment: compiler ==> (attempt to) **turn c source text file into assembler source text file**. (Note: there may be compilers that attempt to, eg, turn C++ into C, that turn BrainFuck into C, that turn C into Pascal, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the programmer's point of view, these are mostly unnecessary steps and most tool chains allow you to invoke compiler + linker with one command.

However, compiling + building a binary usually takes longer time to perform, so you typically don't want to build unless you actually intend to run the program. Often while in the middle of coding, we hit compile to see that we didn't make any silly mistakes, then get on with it. Therefore we want compilation to be as quick as possible.

Also, back in the days when everything was command-line driven, you'd have to manage all the dirty details of how the executable should be built manually. Which files to link, linker options, debugger options, make files. Most tool chains still work like that out of tradition, underneath the hood of the modern IDE.

Some tool chains also allow you to link the .c file into and object file, lib, dll etc that you can provide to other programmers together with a C code header, without exposing all the details of the implementation to them.

From the compiler's point of view, it makes perfect design sense to separate the compiler into the C language compiler, system-specific port of that compiler, and the linker to generate an executable. You wouldn't want to re-write the whole compiler just for porting it between x86 and PowerPC. Everything C-language related could stay the same and you just re-write the parts that generate assembler and binaries.

Answer (score 2):

The `gcc` utility can be used in many different ways. Some of those ways will combine multiple processing steps into a single command-line operation. That doesn't mean those steps don't take place, only that we don't see them.

For example, we can use `gcc` to compile a bunch of source files directly to binaries, combining all the pre-processing, compilation, and link stages into one command. Or we can use `gcc` so that all these steps are separate, if we wish.

For example, `gcc -E` will perform only the pre-processing step. The `-c` switch allows pre-processing and compilation, but stops before linking. If we provide only object files as input, `gcc` will, by default, attempt to link them.

In fact, `gcc` is a hugely complex piece of software with a gazillion command-line switches to control exactly what it does. The fact that some (perhaps many) steps are concealed from the user does not mean they don't happen.

Incidentally, I'd challenge the original assertion that it takes "exactly four steps" to produce an executable. That depends on how sigificant you take an operation to be, to be counted as a distinct "step".